# React(next.js) change state from old Classcomponents to new functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have simple Class component,

```
class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    confirmDirty: false,
    autoCompleteResult: [],
  };
```

and I want to change it to new functions.

```
      const RegistrationForm = () => {

        const [confirmDirty, setconfirmDirty] = useState(false);
        const [autoCompleteResult, setautoCompleteResult] = useState([]);
```

But I am not sure if I did it correctly. Can somebody tell me if it is correct?

Also, can someone point me to material that can help me in the future, because I have problems finding it. Thank for your time and help.

Comment: Looks fine except maybe how the function if being declared i think, see here for official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html